# Flutter video_player progress

Tags: flutter, video, progress

I have a flutter app with [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) and [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie) packages installed. I'm able to play any video without problem, but I need to keep track of the video progress. I tried using a listener, but it doesn't work the way I want it.

```
    _chewieController.addListener(() {
      int seconds = _chewieController.videoPlayerController.value.position.inSeconds;
      if (seconds == 60){ // just an example
        // do some action
      }
    });
```

The listener is never called by the video progress.
What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know about chewie (it looks cool).
I think you should add the listener to the VideoController instance (and not to the chewie controller).

Comment: I changed it to the videoController and it is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

VideoPlayer package give us `VideoProgressIndicator(controller, allowScrubbing: true)`
widget so you can wrap your VideoPlayer in Stack and give VideoProgressIndicator as their child